# How do I auto launch IOS app on received Remote Push Notification (Swift)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is it possible to auto launch app in modal (foreground) without hiding existing app on received Remote Push Notification in IOS (Swift)?

Comment: you cant, the user would either have to open it manually, or swipe the notification

Comment: Make it so awesome the user wants to open it

Comment: I need to open a pop up from the push notification app on top of existing running app. I was able to achieve this in Android. Is this possible in Swift? 
     
Or In simple line on received remote push notification how app should auto popup accept/deny action buttons on top of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is not possible on iOS. You have **absolutely** no way to open your app automatically. It is the user responsibility to open your app.

Comment: Hi Julien. Just I want some action button appear in front  of screen on arrived push notification without hiding any existing foreground app. Which approach should i use for this?

Comment: That's not what you asked in your first question. Please: edit it and carefully explain what you want in details.

Comment: I need to open a pop up from the push notification app on top of existing running app. I was able to achieve this in Android. Is this possible in Swift?

Comment: Or In simple line on received remote push notification how app should auto popup accept/deny action buttons on top of screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to auto launch apps on notification.

Keep in mind, that your user would be in a meeting, his phone streamed on beamer and then your app launches. Or something else. This would be really aweful.

Comment: Hey,  Thanks Daniel for comment on this.. Actually i want some mandatory  action button on Push Notification. since we know that it is possible with Push Notification. But buttons are not appearing on front of users without scroll down region being some times they don't know they need to take some action. Is there any way to achieve this kinds of functionality?

Comment: Hi @Sanjay, the reason your users wouldn't know how they have to interact is, that you are trying to achive an iOS-unnormal interaction-way. Your notification should be filled up with content that will make the user want to tap on the notification. Thats the ever-normal way notifications act with them.

Comment: Hi Daniel, just I want  some action button appear in front of screen on arrived push notification without hiding current existing foreground app. 


Here are my scenario - App (A) (foreground) will send notification to App (B). App(B) will ask some Approval/Cancel Action from user once Approval/Cancel button tapped by user App(A) will start further action.

1. If we tap on notification App(B) will be launch and App (A) will be hide (Background). I want App(A) should always on foreground app after all action

Which approach should i use for this, Please suggest?

Comment: I think this problem is caused by 'failed by design'. Why should B ask for aproval again, if A started the request emmediately?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for prompt response. App (B) is central approval app that's why this Ask. This is our requirement we can't bypass it. 

If you can suggest what approach should i use for this?

Comment: What would be if you push a notification "you have to approve some action" which opens the app, if the user taps on it? Then in the app the user could approve or avoid one or more action-requests. To achive this you could sync these requests with a shared key-chain and sandbox...

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. A push notification generated by App A is received by App B which in turns allows user to "Approve/Reject". Problem that I am facing is that the push notification received by App B is displayed as banner notification on top of the device instead of displaying a popup in foreground of App A.

Either the approve/deny button is displayed in banner notification or the popup opens in the foreground will solve my problem. I have tried but non of these methods work.

Comment: This could be achieved in the notification settings per app, but i do't know whether this can be set as default setting for apps.