# How to open an app automatically when app notification appears with Swift

Tags: swift

I want an app that can be opened automatically or by itself when app notification appears. I've been looking for this case but I don't find any solution.

Comment: You cannot open an app in iOS automatically. If the user taps on the notification then the app can open. But there is no way to force an app to open without user interaction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I auto launch IOS app on received Remote Push Notification (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130908/how-do-i-auto-launch-ios-app-on-received-remote-push-notification-swift)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on iOS. You can not programmatically open an app based on a notification.

What you can do is to use silent pushes (those are push notifications that are invisible to the user) to wake up your application in the background. Using this mechanism, you can do some work in your app in the background (like fetching some data so it is instantly available later on).

Depending on your use case, this might be of use to you.